# jQuery placeholder text once changed can not be changed further

Tags: jquery, wordpress, placeholder

I want to change the text of placeholder. I some how change it with jQuery . After running code my new placeholder is "enter receiver’s email" But now I want to change the placeholder text to "Receiver’s email". I have updated the code.  But placeholder is showing old text  "enter receiver’s email". I don't know why.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#pwgc-to').attr("placeholder", "enter receiver’s email").val("").focus().blur();
    
})
```

The following code has been added to function.php

```js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'change-placeholder', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/change-placeholder.js', // this is the location of your script file
         array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that sets it to `"Receiver’s email"`?

Comment: on this line  $('#pwgc-to').attr("placeholder", "enter receiver’s email").val("").focus().blur(); i just change the placeholder

Comment: Have you enabled any caching plugin in wordpress?

Comment: yes w3 total cache

Comment: clear cache please.

Comment: i have cleared cache but issue not resolved.

Comment: @YasirAltaf try to add a version of your own in the wp_enqeue_script https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ the version will appear in the url so you will check if it is the updated one.

Comment: how to dd version. kindly write a code for me.

Comment: @YasirAltaf something like this perhaps `wp_enqueue_script( 'change-placeholder', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/change-placeholder.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );`

Comment: i have added this '1.0' to code. now what next?

Comment: code has been working fine after disabling w3 cache plugin Can you guide me why this happens?